# django environment pyhon manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, frameworks, environment

trying to start a project with django. I downloaded django and virtualenv package and everything went well ( I followed the installing instructions  ) but, when I trued ti run in the command line : 
python manage.py runserver

it displays an error and says that django does not exist and something about PYHONPATH.

does anybody know a wat to get it installed and start a project easily? some how no matter what I do nothing works. 
thanks

the error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shirl\my_flights\manage.py", line 14, in 
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shirl\my_flights\manage.py", line 16, in 
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate the virtual environment first.